# Too many indices for an array

Tags: python, python-2.7, machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning

How do I solve this issue?

```
def random_mini_batches(train_inputs, train_targets, mini_batch_size = 64, seed = 0):
    m = 17000              
    mini_batches = []
    np.random.seed(seed)

    permutation = list(np.random.permutation(m))
    shuffled_X = train_inputs[:, permutation]
    shuffled_Y = train_targets[:, permutation].reshape((10,m))
```

Error:

```
/home/kkkk/Desktop/ in random_mini_batches(X, Y, mini_batch_size, seed)

    m = 17000              
    mini_batches = []
    np.random.seed(seed)

         49     permutation = list(np.random.permutation(m))
    ---> 50     shuffled_X = train_inputs[:, permutation]
         51     shuffled_Y = train_targets[:, permutation].reshape((10,m))
         52 

    IndexError: too many indices for array
```

Is this something relating to the dimension of the shuffled_X and shuffled_Y?

Comment: what shape has `train_inputs` ? Is it 2-dimensional array ? It looks like it is 1-dimensional array but you use two indiices: first `:` and second `permutation`

Comment: train_inputs = (np.asfarray(all_values[1:]) / 255 * 0.99 ) + 0.01

Comment: what you have in `all_values` - now I see `[1:]` so it can be 1-dimensional array. Display `train_inputs.shape` to see sizes.

Comment: Or maybe you have standard list inside standard list so maybe you should use `[:] [permutation]` instead of `[ : , permutation]`

Comment: The size is (1024,). Seems like something went wrong with the dimensions.

Comment: and what you get for `all_values.shape` or `len(all_values)`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you're trying to do there. 
If X represents a dataset with a D features and Y represents the list of target values for your dataset X, then normally you have that X is a matrix in which each line represents a datapoint. Hence, you should shuffle on the first dimension.

Here there is an example of code:

```
from random import shuffle

indexes = [i for i in range(N)]
shuffle(indexes)
X  = train[indexes, :]
Y = target[indexes,]
```

Comment: X is an array, with m values. Still throwing the same error.

Comment: Try to remove the : in X  = train[indexes, :]

Comment: X  = train[indexes]
Y = target[indexes]